# Using regular expression to parse m3u file

Tags: regex

I am looking to parse a m3u file using a regular expression. The m3u looks like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:36,Artist - Title
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\file1.mp3
#EXTINF:19,Artist - Title
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\file2.mp3
#EXTINF:19,Artist - Title (Additional Title)
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\file3.mp3
#EXTINF:57,Artist - Title - Additional Title
C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\file4.mp3
```

When I open the file in a text editor the m3u is all in one line with no line breaks. I am looking to create two regular expression. The first one would parse the artist and title information. The regex output should be:

```
Artist - Title
Artist - Title
Artist - Title (Additional Title)
Artist - Title - Additional Title
```

The second regex should parse the same information but capture the artist and title in separate groups. The regex output should be:

Group 1

```
Artist
Artist
Artist
Artist
```

Group 2

```
Title
Title
Title (Additional Title)
Title - Additional Title
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To your comment that it shows up as one line in a text editor: are you talking about notepad? If the file uses non-windows line endings (i.e. not `\r\n`), then notepad will not render it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick thought for the first one:

```
#EXTINF:[0-9]+,([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+ - [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?: (?:- [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+|\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\))))?
```

This assumes that both Artist names and song titles will only be composed of letters, digits and spaces (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9 ]), so adjust that to reflect what kind of songs you have and what you can think of.

Furthermore, I've used the python notation for non-capturing groups - (?:) - you may need to replace that based on whatever you'll be using this in.

From there, you can easily split the above to have two capturing groups:

```
#EXTINF:[0-9]+,([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) - ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?: (?:- [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+|\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\))))?
```